# amending harvard in-text citations with page numbers (colon for comma)

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

The style sheet I'm now working to wants this for references within the discussion:

> Smith 1993: 23

I'm using harvard (heavy investment in its specific commands on this document so switching to natbib or biblatex is not labour-saving) which gives this (once parentheses are set to none).

> Smith 1993, 23.

A friend suggested `\renewcommand{\HAR@hisep@agsm}{:}` but this brought no joy.

An equivalent for natbib seems to be `\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}`

A MWE (without the `renewcommand` follows)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\harvardparenthesis{none}

\begin{document}

As one of the chief architects of `civic paganism' puts it:\footnote{\citeasnoun[36 n.3]{north2010a}.}

\bibliographystyle{harvard}

\bibliography{Sente}

\end{document}
```

I spared you documentation of the errors of my different attempts as there were a great number of variants depending on adding different options. I'm currently tryingto get a MWE with the `makeatother` and `makeatletter` wrapper and will post/clarify if I can get it working (not as yet).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you use `makeatletter`?

Comment: As Marco says, you really need to make an example and explain what "brought no joy" means.  Did you get an error, if so what did it say, etc.  But what your friend suggested is correct, but you need to surround the `\renewcommand` line with `\makatletter` and `\makeatother`. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351) for why.

Comment: You're too quick for me Marco, I was trying to correct the edit;)

Comment: Please provide the relevant bib-entry. The bibliography style `harvard` is unknown. Do you mean `agsm`.

Comment: Without more info, for example the BibTeX database entry, we can't hope to answer here.