# Biblatex Harvard style: Amend In-Text Referencing

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

There is [a very similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114262/amending-harvard-in-text-citations-with-page-numbers-colon-for-comma) to this post but it was never resolved; I couldn't find any quick solution neither, probably because it is a noob issue... Hopefully someone can provide an answer for a confused noob.

Currently `biblatex` generated author-year style in-text citation like the following:

> (Smith 2006 p. 50)

I am looking to add commas between each element of an in-text citation, like so:

> (Smith, 2006, p. 50)

My current code for `biblatex` (I believe most are for modifying the full citation in bibliography, so it'd be helpful to point out where I can edit):

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authoryear,maxbibnames=99,giveninits=true,innamebeforetitle=true,dashed=false,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{1.bib}
%force forcing the bib entries not to be split across pages, which is done by setting \interlinepenalty to 10000.
\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
  \interlinepenalty=10000\relax % default is 5000
  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
  \raggedbottom
  \frenchspacing
  \biburlsetup}
% space between biblio items
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}
%Last-First name order
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
% Put editor string in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

% Print editors before "in" title
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addspace}
 
%remove pp in-text citations
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
} 
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\NewBibliographyString{available}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    available = {Available at},
    urlseen = {accessed on}
    andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}
```

My `1.bib` file:

```
@book{Smith2006,
publisher = {Routledge},
title = {Uses of heritage},
year = 2006,
author = {Smith, Laurajane},
address = {London},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The punctuation between name and year in citations is controlled by the context-sensitive delimiter `nameyeardelim`. The punctuation between year and the postnote/page range by `postnotedelim`.

So you probably want something like

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

In total (with a few small changes to make some things more idiomatic, comment if you want hints about that)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
  \interlinepenalty=10000\relax % default is 5000
  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
  \raggedbottom
  \frenchspacing
  \biburlsetup}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.7\itemsep}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}


\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addspace}
 
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

%remove pp in-text citations
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\NewBibliographyString{available}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  available = {Available at},
  urlseen   = {accessed on}
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \UndeclareBibstringSet{latin}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[12]{worman}
dolor \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998) ipsum (Worman, 2002, 12) dolor (Aksın et al., 2006)]

Comment: Hello, many thanks for the comment. I tried following your modification (I even copied and pasted to check if I got any parts wrong), but the compilation end up popping up the message "Undefined control sequence" regarding on \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{andothers}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
The line seem to obstruct rendering the entire document as well.
What should I do?

Comment: @madguy224488 If `\DeclareBibstringSetFormat` is undefined your `biblatex` version is too old. You may want to look into updating your TeX system. The line was an alternative solution to making the "et al." italic. If you cannot update and are stuck with an outdated `biblatex` you can still go back to your previous code for that.